# How does Qt select a default style?

Tags: c++, qt, qapplication, qstyle

In a Qt GUI application, `QApplication::style()->objectName()` will return the current style, for example "windowsvista".

How/where does it choose this default style, and what information does it use to decide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt comes with builtin styles, these are (on my 5.9.2):

- Windows
- WindowsXP
- WindowsVista
- Android
- Fusion
- Macintosh

each one having its own class, derived from `QStyle`.

To see which ones are available (it depends on Qt build configuration):

```
const auto & styles = QStyleFactory::keys();
for(const auto & s : styles)
{
    qDebug() << s;
}
```

Custom plugins (i.e. libraries in the QTDIR/plugins/styles directory) would be shown as well, if present.

**How the default style is chosen?**

Default style is searched in `QApplication` method `style()`, in *qapplication.cpp* file, in this order:

1. The style override, if set by the environment variable `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` (this is set in `QApplicationPrivate::process_cmdline()`);
2. The style returned by `QApplicationPrivate::desktopStyleKey()` (this method loads a list of styles from the current platform theme and select the first name from this list that is present in the `QStyleFactory::keys()` list);
3. The first item in `QStyleFactory::keys()` list.

If a style could not be determined, the function will assert

```
Q_ASSERT(!"No styles available!");
```

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation:

> Qt contains a set of QStyle subclasses that emulate the styles of the
>   different platforms supported by Qt (QWindowsStyle, QMacStyle etc.).

You can set the style by using a key: `windowsvista` for example, `fusion`, `macintosh`, etc. When using any key, the style returned will be a subclass of QStyle. Depending on the platform you're using, you will have access to a certain number of keys.

> How/where does it choose this default style

It is done in the [QStyleFactory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylefactory.html) source [file](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/styles/qstylefactory.cpp?h=dev). You can also take a look a the QStyle source [file](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/styles/qstyle.cpp?h=dev) to get a hang of what's going on.

> what information does it use to decide

The default style is platform dependent, and then you can choose any style among the keys at your disposition on this platform.